# Deleting field from content type and database

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, content-type

When you delete a field of a content type from Drupal 7, does it delete it from the database as well?
For example I have a content type with 20 fields and about 250000 nodes. If I delete a field, will it delete the 250000 field values as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes -- all data from that field will be deleted because the table in the database containing the data will be deleted.

Comment: This is not exactly true, as it is not always the case. Please have look to my answer to this same question.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a field from a content type in Drupal 7 (and possibly Drupal 8, but I am not yet sure) it gets away from your content type and you cannot access the data any more. Nevertheless, if you have more than a small amount of nodes with values for that field, the actual content may remain in the database for a time, in tables named like `field_deleted_data_<NUMBER>`, where `<NUMBER>` is the id of your field in the `field_config` table.

The data gets actually purged from the database in small batches over the time via hook_cron. The amount of data that gets deleted on each run of cron is defined in the `field_purge_batch_size` variable, which has by default a value of `10` (in `field.module`). When there is no data left in the table, the remaining field configuration data are deleted too.

You can check Drupal API documentation for [field_delete_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_delete_field/7) and [field_purge_batch](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_purge_batch/7) for further references.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean it'll delete only 10 rows every cron cycle?! If htats the case can I just delete the table directly from the database?

Comment: Don't do that! You need to let Drupal do things in its own way, or you get impredictable errors. You may, however, declare a higher value for `field_purge_batch_size` in order to speed up data deletion.

Comment: If you really want to tamper with the database, you may try to manually `TRUNCATE` the table, and let Drupal get rid of the table itself. But I do not recommend it and I don't know if any other problem could arise.